# Android ADB Cannot Find Samsung Captivate

Tags: android, usb, adb

I have tried downloading the Samsung specific drivers.  It installs the modem, not sure if the adb bridge got installed.  I don't see it in the device manager.  I have installed kies 2.0, I have tried connecting USB via MASS storage, via Kies, and under no circumstances so far will ADB detect the device when running adb devices command.  I got lots of suggestions to use Kies, I tried this. Don't see any real relationship between Kies and ADB which is a debug bridge.   I simply have no clue what ADB is doing when I type adb devices.  How does it look for devices, where does it check, where can i register my device with ADB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently sometimes you need to uninstall and reinstall the driver multiple times before it works (http://androidforums.com/captivate-all-things-root/136373-adb-shell-error-device-not-found.html).  Also, make sure that USB debugging is turned in your application settings.

Comment: alright I will look at this.  Also can you tell me what setting are required for ADB connection.  USB settings to mass storage?

Comment: also I am seeing Samsung Modem software installed correctly ???  I downloaded the drivers as a whole not sure why it refers to just modem.

Comment: Ok.  I reinstalled.  An your suggestion about USB Debuging on was also needed.  I thought it was on because I saw the checkbox checked but grayed out.  It needs to show checked and green.   So just reinstall and USB debugging and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are using the correct drivers (32 bit or 64 bit).  when you connect your phone in debug mode check device manager.  I would bet you have an error in there. Try and delete the error and rescan for changes.