# Android newbie - debugging app on physical device

Tags: android

I was trying to debug my code on a physical device instead of an emulator. In order to do this after a series of steps I finally plugged in my device only to see that "Samsung_Android" and "CDC serial" drivers are missing.

It seems very odd for these drivers to be missing. What am I doing wrong, any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what are all of the steps you took to get to where you now are?

Comment: Downloaded Kies, on AndroidManifest.xml added a line to indicate debuggable as true, on my phone enabled the usb debugging and configured the ide to not to run automatically on a virtual device

Comment: Don't think it is really releavent but I have Samsung Galaxy s2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the usb drivers for ADB. For samsung, you need to install kies, located [here.](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobilesoftwaremanual/mobilesoftwaremanual.do?page=MOBILE.SOFTWARE.MANUAL) Also, if you have problems there are some stack overflow related questions, like [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921826/android-adb-cannot-find-samsung-captivate)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have kies installed? Go to C:\Program Files\Samsung\Kies (or whatever folder) and look for a folder named USB driver. Instal the executable inside, make sure kies is not running and connect the phone to the computer. It should work just fine